# How do I raise an exception in an asm block?

Tags: delphi, exception, assembly, 64-bit

I want to raise an exception in a X64 asm block.

Lets assume I have a function like so:

```
function Example(Values: array of integer): integer;
asm
  or rcx,rcx
  jz @error
  ....
```

I know I can just read the pointer and get a AV, however I want to raise a more descriptive error.

I could make an additional function and call that one:

```
asm
  or rcx,rcx
  jz @error
  ....
@error:
  mov ecx, 1
  mov rdx, ErrorString
  jmp RaiseError
  ....

function RaiseError(code: integer; const Msg: string);
begin
  case code of
    1: raise EEmptyArrayError.Create(Msg);
```

However the error will then occur outside the function in which is was caused. How do I get the exception to (seem to) originate from inside the `Example` function.

Note that this is X64, so all the SEH answers that apply to X86 are no good because X64 uses VEH.

Comment: I think it's still SEH in x64. And just write some Pascal and see what the compiler emits to work it out.

Comment: Since no one else is going to ask, if the code is high level enough that you want it to raise exceptions, why are you writing it in assembly in the first place?

Comment: Because it needs SSE instructions, and I don't have SSE-intrinsics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full syntax of raise is:

```
raise Exception at address
```

All you need to do is to pass the current IP as a parameter and the error proc can pass that on to the exception.

You can get the RIP using `lea rax, [rip]`.

Thus the code becomes:

```
asm
  or rcx,rcx
  jz @error
  ....
@error:
  mov ecx, 1
  mov rdx, ErrorString
  lea r8,[rip]
  jmp RaiseError 
  ....

function RaiseError(code: integer; const Msg: string; address: pointer);
begin
  case code of
    1: raise EEmptyArrayError.Create(Msg) at address;
```

Of course in this case it's easier to use

```
function RaiseError(code: integer; const Msg: string);
begin
  case code of
    1: raise EEmptyArrayError.Create(Msg) at ReturnAddress;
```

**Note**
In this case if you keep the jmp the error will seem to originate from the calling routine, in this case that's actually correct. If you want the exception to point the guilty finger at your asm code then use a call.

Comment: In Delphi XE2+, you can (and should) use the `System.ReturnAddress` compiler intrinsic, which works in both 32bit and 64bit: `procedure RaiseError(code: integer; const Msg: string); begin ... raise EEmptyArrayError.Create(Msg) at ReturnAddress; ... end;`

Comment: I think you must use `call RaiseError` instead of `jmp RaiseError` when using the `RaiseError` version with `ReturnAddress`.

Comment: @JRL No the jmp is correct. In this case the error is not in my asm code the error is in the routine that calls that code with a nil parameter. the exception should display that.   otherwise the user will debug the wrong routine.